# How to calculate the response time of several Ajax requests that are subsequently sended when a particular dom element is clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to dynamically calculate the response time of a search API on my page. The only thing I can listen to is the button click event that directly caused the request to be sent. So is there any solution for this?

```
// click this button, there will be a XHR call to be send.
<button id="submit-btn">submit</button>;


/**
 * @param dom It could be any DOM element on the page.
 */
function getDomRelatedAjaxRspTime(dom) {
  return new Promise((r, j) => {
    dom.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (there is some XHR sended) {
         let domRelatedAjaxRspTime = 0;
         *get domRelatedAjaxRspTime time* // How to implement here?
         r(domRelatedAjaxRspTime);
      } else {
         r(0); // no xhr send, return 0;
      }
    });
  });
}

const dom = document.querySelector('#submit-btn');
getDomRelatedAjaxRspTime(dom).then(domRelatedAjaxRspTime => {
  console.log(domRelatedAjaxRspTime);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give each call a  unique name and invoke the console.time(). Once you get a response clear the timer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest console.time() for time tracking.

put console.time() at start of button click and console.timeEnd() in ajax success.

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    //Starting Console Timer
    console.time("AJAX");
    $.ajax({
      method:"get",
      url:"https://httpbin.org/get",
      success:function(){
        //Ending Console Timer
        console.timeEnd("AJAX");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Here</button>
```